# What is the difference in crontab between */5 and 0/5?

Tags: linux, cron

What is the difference in crontab between */5 and 0/5 in minutes definition? I did not find that specification in crontab documentation. Quartz scheduler defines 0/5 as every 5 minutes (http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06), but this is a different thing than crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It performs the command every 5 minutes between 0 minutes and 0 minutes. This has the same effect as omitting the "/5" since there is only a single minute period in which this will be true.